# what does "heading into" mean here?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

Is this two sentences equal in the meaning?

> the champions heading into the match
>
> the champions going into the match

What does "heading into" mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meanings are essentially the same, although "going into" makes it sound like the match is coming up very soon or immediately, while with "heading into" it might still be some time away (like a few days).